# Find this maximum value the sum $x_1+\cdots+x_n$ may achieve

Tags: number-theory, inequality

I had read a hard problem on [AOPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2677576&sid=b9715ccd7479cdbd20dab4701a771bf7#p2677576)

Given an integer $n\geq 2$, determine the maximum value the sum $x_1+\cdots+x_n$ may achieve, as the $x_i$ run through the positive integers, subject to $x_1\leq x_2\leq \cdots \leq x_n$ and $x_1+\cdots+x_n=x_1 x_2\cdots x_n$

Comment: The answer given in the forum link
$$
x_1 = n, \quad x_2 = 2, \quad x_3 = x_4 = \cdots = x_n = 1
$$
looks like it may very well always yield the maximum sum.  I would try to prove that any other integer solution must have a lower sum.

Comment: what is the question?